# Printf does not work unless another printf is present

Tags: c

I was trying to solve a challenge in C on HackerRank. There is a square matrix with n rows and columns.The challenge is to print the absolute difference between the two sums of the matrix's diagonals as a single integer.

Here's the link:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference

I'm able to get the correct answer but the printf() statement at the end of the code does not work unless I add an unnecessary  printf("") before the for loop statement.
Could someone explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Here's the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int n; 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n][n],sum_d1=0,sum_d2=0,a_i,a_j;
    for( a_i = 1; a_i <= n; a_i++)
    {
       for(a_j = 1; a_j <= n; a_j++)
       {
           scanf("%d",&a[a_i][a_j]);
           if(a_j==a_i)
               sum_d1=sum_d1+a[a_i][a_j];
       }
    }
    printf("");// the last printf works only when this statement is present
    for(a_i=1;a_i<=n;a_i++)
    {
        for(a_j=n;a_j>0;a_j--)
        {
            if((a_i+a_j)==(n+1))
                sum_d2=sum_d2+a[a_i][a_j];
        }
    }
    printf("%d",abs(sum_d1-sum_d2)); //this doesn't work if there is no printf above
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behaviour because you are indexing your array at position `[n]`.

Comment: You also have a missing newline bug.  Add `\n` to the end of your format string to fix it.  That way the line will end properly, rather than dangling upon program exit.

Comment: @TomKarzes Why would the empty string printf before that fix that?

Comment: You main bug is that you're treating your arrays as if they are indexed from 1..n.  They are not.  Valid indexes run from 0..(n-1). Very few languages use one-based indexing today.

Comment: Since you're accessing outside the array bounds, you're corrupting some memory. It's just random chance that the extra `printf` call causes the second `printf` to work. Fix your bug.

Comment: @Barmar There's no way to predict it.  The code is corrupting the stack.  So obviously adding and removing seemingly unrelated code could have all kinds of effects, since it will affect memory allocation.  That's why it's called *undefined behavior*, and why it's a waste of time to try to predict what it will do.  Just fix it.

Comment: @TomKarzes Isn't that what I just wrote? Why do you think adding a newline would help?

Comment: @Barmar You asked why the empty string printf would "fix it".  The obvious interpretation was that you meant OP's problem, but I now realize you misread my comment.  I pointed out a separate formatting bug, and explained how to fix it.  You misinterpreted what it would fix.

Answer (score 3):

The trailing newline is the key here.  Standard out only flushes when it encounters a line ending for performance reasons.  If you change to fprintf(stderr, ...) then your code will work as is. You could also use fflush(stdout) after your printf's.

Answer (score 1):

As a couple of other people have mentioned, your main issue is your array declaration / use. Arrays in C have their first index from 0, not from 1. As such, when you try and store things in your array, or access them again, it is out of the boundary of the array, and may act in a way unintended.

Array example: Array[2][3]

```
    0  1 
0  a|  b | 
1  c|  d | 
2  e|  f |

Array[0][0] == a 
Array[1][1] == d 
Array[1][2] == f
```

In your code, if someone enters "1", an array of size [1][1] is created - a single element. This should be accessed using a[0][0], but in the code is being accessed by a[1][1], which is an invalid element, as it is not a part of the array.

Without knowing exactly what you intend your code to do, I cannot fix it entirely, but a good start would be as below:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){
    int n; 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n][n],sum_d1=0,sum_d2=0,a_i,a_j;
    for( a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++){
       for(a_j = 0; a_j < n; a_j++){
           scanf("%d",&a[a_i][a_j]);
           if(a_j==a_i)
               sum_d1=sum_d1+a[a_i][a_j];
       }
    }
    //printf("");// the last printf works only when this statement is present
    for(a_i=0;a_i<n;a_i++)
    {
        for(a_j=n-1;a_j>=0;a_j--)
        {
            if((a_i+a_j)==(n+1))
                sum_d2=sum_d2+a[a_i][a_j];
        }
    }
    printf("%d",abs(sum_d1-sum_d2)); //this doesn't work if there is no printf above
    return 0;
}
```